# How do I bulk copy AMI AWS account number permissions from one AMI image to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-ami

I have an AMI image which is private and via the Permissions tab I have made the image available to several dozen AWS account numbers.

I have a new AMI image that I would like to make available to the same AWS accounts as the original image.

I can cut and paste each account number into the Permissions tab dialog on the new AMI image... but that seems very tedious.  Is there a way to bulk copy the AWS account number permissions set on one AMI image to another AMI image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to script this using the AWS CLI command `aws ec2 modify-image-attribute`

See some of the examples in [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-image-attribute.html). Specifically the example titled **"To grant launch permission to an AWS account"**